# Compensation for Full Time Moderators

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Do moderators here get any kind of compensation for all their efforts and help?

Comment: [Answered on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169205/263383).

Comment: @ACuriousMind I love that answer! Thanks I got to be nicer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind it should be posted here as well as a reminder.

Comment: Please keep it here too.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/848/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PersonArtPhoto's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169222/184688) on the Meta Stack Exchange question linked to in the comments:

> The benefits of being a moderator:
>
> 1. A huge say in the direction of a site.
> 2. Access to the site views.
> 3. The ability to choose an organization of a list of a few to receive $100 once a year from Stack Exchange.
> 4. More direct access to the Stack Exchange employees.
> 5. That warm fuzzy feeling of making a difference.
> 6. Access to the Teacher's Lounge, a chat room for moderators.
> 7. Once in a blue moon, SE will hire one of the community moderators as "Community Managers".
>
> As has been noted, SE staff also has access, who do get paid. But
>   there are some 200+ (Maybe even more?) moderators, including myself,
>   who don't receive a dime for their services.

In case it needs to be said explicitly, [moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) do not receive any financial compensation for their activities on the site.